# TypeError: render is not a function Context Api Multiple Context

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, producer-consumer, react-context

I want to change the background of my web app dynamically so I want to use a context that includes a context. I am getting this error : TypeError: render is not a function.
This is ThemeContext.js:

```js
class BookList extends Component {
    render() {

        
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer> {(contextTheme) => (
                <BookContext.Consumer>
                    {contextBook => {
                        
                        const {books} = contextBook;
                        const { isDarkTheme, dark, light } = contextTheme;
                        const theme = isDarkTheme ? dark : light;  
                        return (
                        ...
                        ...
                         )
                    }}
                </BookContext.Consumer>
            )}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>
        
        )
    }
}
export default BookList;
```

This is BookList.js so it is a component.

```js
class ThemeContextProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isDarkTheme : true,
        dark: { bg: '#d2f3df', txt: '#0f0f0f', hover: '#f0f0f0ca'},
        light : {bg : '#288888', txt: '#f0f0f0', hover : '#f0f0f0ca'}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

This is the child context(BookContext):

```js
import React from 'react';

export const BookContext = React.createContext();

class BookContextProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
    ...
    ...
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <BookContext.Provider value= {this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </BookContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
export default BookContextProvider;
```

Comment: Try to remove the double {{ }} here `<ThemeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>` with only one {}

Comment: When I remove it, I get an error from the terminal.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: 'Syntax Error: Unexpected Token.' if I remove one of two brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the render method you need to import component from react or access it using React.Component:

```
// import React
import React from 'react';

// create class as extension of React.Component
class BookList extends React.Component {
    render() {

        
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer> {(contextTheme) => (
                <BookContext.Consumer>
                    {contextBook => {
                        
                        const {books} = contextBook;
                        const { isDarkTheme, dark, light } = contextTheme;
                        const theme = isDarkTheme ? dark : light;  
                        return (
                        ...
                        ...
                         )
                    }}
                </BookContext.Consumer>
            )}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>
        
        )
    }
}
export default BookList;
```

As a side note I would recommend using functional components. You are not using in this component so it's best to use it as a function. Even when you want to use state in a functional component you can then use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Here it is as a functional component:

```
const BookList = () => {
return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer> {(contextTheme) => (
                <BookContext.Consumer>
                    {contextBook => {

                        const {books} = contextBook;
                        const { isDarkTheme, dark, light } = contextTheme;
                        const theme = isDarkTheme ? dark : light;  
                        return (
                        ...
                        ...
                         )
                    }}
                </BookContext.Consumer>
            )}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>

        )
}

export default BookList
```

Comment: I know them. I didn't just share unnecessary sides of the code.